# How to a record such as inventory value

Tags: vb.net

I'll post below the file I'm given for school. Basically I have a stock amount and a sale price. I have to figure out how to show the value for each 
item. The only I would know how to do this is by doing one at a time.

Stock#, Descrip, Sale Price, Iventory

ET001,  1 Drawer End table, 169.99, 10

ET002,  2 Drawer End table, 289.95, 05

ET003,  6 Drawer End table, 129.99, 02

ST001,  Stacking Table,     320.75, 20

Comment: What is the question? What you want to do with data? Show in the UI?, Save to the database? Show what did you tried and where is your exact problem

Comment: I figured it out. When I was reading the data and trying to find the total for each item it was only giving me the total of all the items. Turns out I was writing to the wrong long.

Answer (score 0):

You will still need to read in the file and parse the contents. I would suggest using a `StreamReader` inside a `Using` block to read each line of text and then `.Split(",")` the line data to get the values. Once you have the values parsed it should be fairly straight forward using this simple console application as a starting point.

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        ' Create a list to hold the items
        Dim slist As New List(Of StockItem)

        ' Get your file contents and parse out the data then add it to the list. Done manually below
        slist.Add(New StockItem With {.StockCode = "ET001", .Description = "1 Drawer End table", .SalePrice = 169.99D, .Inventory = 10I})
        slist.Add(New StockItem With {.StockCode = "ET002", .Description = "2 Drawer End table", .SalePrice = 289.99D, .Inventory = 5I})

        'Loop Through all Items and get the values. 
        For Each item As StockItem In slist
            'Write it out to the Debug
            Debug.WriteLine(item.GetValue())
        Next
    End Sub
End Module

Public Structure StockItem
    Public Property StockCode As String
    Public Property Description As String
    Public Property SalePrice As Decimal
    Public Property Inventory As Integer

    Public Function GetValue() As Decimal
        Return CDec(Me.SalePrice * Me.Inventory)
    End Function
End Structure
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll actually have to look at this. For now I got done with what I needed for class. I was writing to the wrong line so it displayed 1 total instead of all of them